# Loading a view controller from viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

Hello I want to create a tabbar application in iPhone using X-code.I have one splash screen and then after that I have my Home Screen where I want to create tabbar in that view. so, I create a tabbar in my ViewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"in Home");
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];        
    homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];  
    NextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc]init];   

    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeViewController,nextViewController,nil];    
     window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
     [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];                                             
     [window makeKeyAndVisible]; 

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Now when I compile & Run, It will call the HomeView again & again and when I tap on 2nd tab it will not call the NextView.

So, what is wrong in this code Plz help me..

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you adding the homeViewController again and again since viewDidLoad is in homeViewController...

Comment: But if I dont add it then It will not display me the tabbar properly

Comment: i think that you need to make a rootcontroller

Comment: ok thanx but can you give me the code for that, how tabbar is included in that

Answer (score 1):

Can I recommend that you start a new project from the `Tab Bar Application` template just to look at how it's done when it's done right?   You might even keep that and retrofit your splash screen into it.